# How to correct company website classification at the database level from companies like Sophos

Tags: url, security, domain-registration, spam-blocker

A Corporate client using web blocker such as Sophos cannot access our company website.  Blocker comes back and indicates our site is "Sex Education" however it is mental health education.  I know the Corporate Client can add an exception rule to allow access.
This is a broader question which is how to get data blocker companies such as Sophos to reclassify / correctly classify non-profit as a mental health organization. Is there a central database that can be updated that will distribute to all blocking software correct website classification?  Or perhaps the non-profit URL was not classified correctly when establised?  Thanks...

Comment: I'm not aware of a single UTM ([Unified Threat Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_threat_management)) database, but I think Sophos and many others use McAfee's. You can request re-categorization for your site [here](https://www.trustedsource.org/).

Comment: Thank you Dan... I'll follow up on this.  Steve